# No hay claves principales ni candidatas en la tabla a la que se hace referencia

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo un problema en [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) me esta dando este error al crear la base de datos.

> Mens. 1776, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 95 No hay claves principales ni
>   candidatas en la tabla a la que se hace referencia ('ESTANCOS') que
>   concuerden con la lista de columnas que hace la referencia en la clave
>   externa 'FK_BODEGAS1'. Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 95 No se
>   pudo crear la restricción o el índice. Vea los errores anteriores.

```
--Tabla Estancos
CREATE TABLE ESTANCOS(
    ID_FABRICA INT NOT NULL,
    NUM_EXPENDIDURIA INT NOT NULL,
    CODIGO_DEL_ESTANCO INT NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_ESTANCO VARCHAR(25),
    DIRECCION_ESTANCO VARCHAR(25),
    LOCALIDAD_ESTANCO VARCHAR(25),
    PROVINCIA_ESTANCO VARCHAR(25)
);

ALTER TABLE ESTANCOS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ESTANCOS PRIMARY KEY(ID_FABRICA,NUM_EXPENDIDURIA,CODIGO_DEL_ESTANCO);


-----------------------------------------------------------------------


--Tabla Bodegas
CREATE TABLE BODEGAS(
    ID_FABRICA INT NOT NULL,
    MARCA VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    FILTRO CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(FILTRO = 'S' OR FILTRO ='N'), --S o N
    COLOR CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(COLOR = 'Negra' OR COLOR ='Rubia'), --Negra o rubia
    CLASE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK(CLASE = 'Normal' OR CLASE ='light' OR CLASE ='Ultralight'), --Normal, light o ultralight
    MENTOL CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(MENTOL = 'S' OR MENTOL ='N'), --S o N
    UNIDADES INT

);

ALTER TABLE BODEGAS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_BODEGAS PRIMARY KEY(ID_FABRICA, MARCA, FILTRO, COLOR, CLASE, MENTOL);

ALTER TABLE BODEGAS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BODEGAS1 FOREIGN KEY(ID_FABRICA) REFERENCES ESTANCOS(ID_FABRICA) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE BODEGAS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BODEGAS2 FOREIGN KEY(MARCA,FILTRO,COLOR,CLASE,MENTOL) REFERENCES CIGARROS(MARCA,FILTRO,COLOR,CLASE,MENTOL) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es el siguiente, en la foreign key de "BODEGAS" siguiente:

```
ALTER TABLE BODEGAS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_BODEGAS1 FOREIGN KEY(ID_FABRICA) REFERENCES ESTANCOS(ID_FABRICA) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Estás haciendo referencia a una columna de la tabla "ESTANCOS" que no es la PRIMARY KEY, ya que la PRIMARY KEY de esta tabla la tienes definida como un conjunto de columnas:

```
ALTER TABLE ESTANCOS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ESTANCOS PRIMARY KEY(ID_FABRICA,NUM_EXPENDIDURIA,CODIGO_DEL_ESTANCO);
```

Por lo que si tu quieres hacer una FOREIGN KEY a una columna que no es PRIMARY KEY deberás hacer que esa columna sea **UNIQUE** como se indica en la [documentación](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

Traducción:

> Una restricción FOREIGN KEY no tiene que estar vinculada sólo a una
>   restricción de PRIMARY KEY en otra tabla; También se puede definir para
>   hacer referencia a las columnas con una restricción UNIQUE en otra
>   tabla.

Comment: Estimado entonces lo unico que tengo que hacer es en la tabla ESTANCOS añadir la palabra unique, y la tabla quedaria CREATE TABLE ESTANCOS(
    ID_FABRICA INT NOT NULL UNIQUE, ..... ) ? gracias de antemano

Comment: Si no me equivoco con eso sería suficiente para poder referenciar esa columna con la FOREIGN KEY

Comment: Me sirvio de mucho la respuesta, solo habia que agregar el UNIQUE EN CADA VARIABLE GRACIAS!!!

Comment: Me alegro @FernandoBanegas que te haya servido! Saludos!